# MySQL - GROUP BY - evaluate separate, then combine

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT app.application_id, j.job_id,
CASE
WHEN r.role_name = 'role1' THEN (SELECT user_id FROM job_roles WHERE job_id = j.job_id AND role_id = r.role_id)
ELSE 0
END as recruiter, 
CASE
WHEN r.role_name = 'role2' THEN (SELECT user_id FROM job_roles WHERE job_id = j.job_id AND role_id = r.role_id)
ELSE 0
END as viewer
FROM app_pending_approvals apa 
JOIN process_approval_reqs par ON par.approval_req_id = apa.approval_req_id
JOIN applications app ON app.application_id = apa.application_id
JOIN roles r ON r.role_id = par.role_id
JOIN user_roles ON user_roles.role_id = r.role_id
JOIN users ON users.user_id = user_roles.user_id
JOIN onboarding_process_elements ope ON ope.element_id = par.process_element_id
JOIN onboarding_process_elements ope1 ON ope1.element_id = app.process_element_id
JOIN onboarding_process_elements ope2 ON ope2.element_id = app.pending_element_id
JOIN jobs j ON j.job_id = app.job_id
WHERE (ope.percent_complete >= ope1.percent_complete)
AND (ope.percent_complete <= ope2.percent_complete)
```

That returns something like this:

```
application_id | job_id | role1 | role2
---------------------------------------
146            | 61231  | 5     | 0
146            | 61231  | 0     | 7
```

However, my desired output is this:

```
application_id | job_id | role1 | role2
---------------------------------------
146            | 61231  | 5     | 7
```

But when I use "GROUP BY app.application_id" I get the following:

```
application_id | job_id | role1 | role2
---------------------------------------
146            | 61231  | 5     | 0
```

I realize that GROUP BY is doing exactly what it is supposed to do, is there any other way I can get my desired output? Or am I stuck with having separate rows? Can I use an aggregate on the CASE columns to weed out values of 0? Forgive me if I'm missing something trivial here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT app.application_id, j.job_id,
SUM(CASE
WHEN r.role_name = 'role1' THEN (SELECT user_id FROM job_roles WHERE job_id = j.job_id AND role_id = r.role_id)
ELSE 0
END) as recruiter, 
SUM(CASE
WHEN r.role_name = 'role2' THEN (SELECT user_id FROM job_roles WHERE job_id = j.job_id AND role_id = r.role_id)
ELSE 0
END) as viewer
FROM app_pending_approvals apa 
JOIN process_approval_reqs par ON par.approval_req_id = apa.approval_req_id
JOIN applications app ON app.application_id = apa.application_id
JOIN roles r ON r.role_id = par.role_id
JOIN user_roles ON user_roles.role_id = r.role_id
JOIN users ON users.user_id = user_roles.user_id
JOIN onboarding_process_elements ope ON ope.element_id = par.process_element_id
JOIN onboarding_process_elements ope1 ON ope1.element_id = app.process_element_id
JOIN onboarding_process_elements ope2 ON ope2.element_id = app.pending_element_id
JOIN jobs j ON j.job_id = app.job_id
WHERE (ope.percent_complete >= ope1.percent_complete)
AND (ope.percent_complete <= ope2.percent_complete)
GROUP BY app.application_id, j.job_id
```

Comment: Yes, You can use MAX CLAUSE for strings

Comment: MAX(CASE
WHEN r.role_name = 'role2' THEN (SELECT user_id FROM job_roles WHERE job_id = j.job_id AND role_id = r.role_id)
ELSE ''
END) if field varchar type

Comment: Yuppp! I just tested it, success! thanks for the advice I should have known to use that.